# if (fork()) fork()

Tags: c, fork

I am studying for an OS quiz and I did not understand what output

```
if(fork())
    fork()
```

will produce.  Can someone explain?

I didn't understand this line:

```
if(fork())
```

**Edit:**

What I meant with "output" is how many processes will be there if this code was executed.

Sorry I'm a bit dizzy after studying.

Comment: That will output...nothing.  The question surely includes a printf or something else that outputs after the forks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a hint: `if (fork())` is just a short way of writing `if (fork() != 0)`.

Comment: I'd rather think `if(x!=0)` is a long way of writing `if(x)`.  :)

Comment: hehe question in quiz was:  if(!fork()) if(!fork()) if(fork()) fork() got the full mark out of it <3

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you are best off just trying it, reading the [documentation](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) for fork, and then, if it still doesn't make sense, asking a more specific question about what part you don't understand.

Start by trying this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv){
    int x,y=0;
    x = fork();
    if (x) y = fork();
    printf("x: %d, y: %d\n",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i had a same problem like you.

the meaning of  ::::::> `if (fork())`

`if (fork() !=0)`, and as you know:

- `fork()`: can take 3 values!
- `fork() = 0` for child.
- `fork() < 0` error.
- `fork() > 0` parent.

So:

`if ( 0 != O )` ==> false (in this case you dont have to do the 2 fork())

`if (-123 != 0 )` ==> True (yes you have).

`if (5 != 0 )` ==> true (yes you have).

good like

Answer (score 0):

for parent

```
if (fork()) is
```

evaluated as

```
if(pid_of_child)
```

and for child process it is evaluated as:

```
if(0)
```

that is it :)